# How to find $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin4x}{\sin2x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find the limit $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin4x}{\sin2x}\,?$$

Should I do  $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin4x}{4x}}{\dfrac{\sin2x}{2x}}\,?$$

This doesn't seem to look right, could you show me the way ?

Comment: Calculating this limit should be able to give the original limit. You can also recall that $\sin(2y)=2\sin(y)\cos(y)$.

Comment: Notice that $$\frac{\frac{\sin(4x)}{4x}}{\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}} = \frac{2x}{4x} \frac{\sin(4x)}{\sin(2x)} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin(4x)}{\sin(2x)}.$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Keen-ameteur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/421273/keen-ameteur) points out, we can use:

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin 4x}{\sin 2x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {2\sin 2x \cos 2x}{\sin 2x}=\lim_{x \to 0}2\cos (2x)=2\cos (2\cdot 0)=2\cos 0=2\cdot 1=2$$

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed write :

$$  \frac{\sin(4x)}{\sin(2x)} =  2 \cdot\frac{\sin(4x)}{4x} \cdot \frac{2x}{\sin(2x)} $$

And now, because
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \xrightarrow{x \rightarrow 0} 1 $$

you get 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(4x)}{\sin(2x)} = 2.$$

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close,

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin4x}{\sin2x}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin4x}{4x}}{\dfrac{\sin2x}{\color{green}{2\cdot}2x}}=2.$$